# How to access S3 bucket with this strange plain text file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I got text file to access S3 bucket like following:

```
arn:aws:iam::############:user/aaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaa-aaa
User
aaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaa-aaa
Access key ID
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Secret access key
AAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action": [ 
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::bbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbb/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have AWS account and can create my own buckets, but see no UI to acquire such files.

**UPDATE**

I issued

```
>aws s3 ls
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

then I did

```
>aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: AAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Default region name [None]:
Default output format [None]:
```

and now

```
>aws s3 ls
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

Why? Why didn't I use neither `User` nor `Resource` values from my text file or how to use this data?

**UPDATE 2**

I tried

```
>aws s3 ls

>aws s3 ls s3://bbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbb

>aws s3 ls bbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbb

>aws s3 ls bbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbb/*

>aws s3 ls s3:/bbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbb
```

And got `Access denied` in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your System Administrators have created some configurations in AWS and they wanted to let you know what they have done. The file is a dump of information from various locations -- it is for your reference and is not for 'use' somewhere.

The first line is the Amazon Resource Name (ARN) that uniquely identifies you as a user. It can be used in security policies to grant you access to resources:

```
arn:aws:iam::############:user/aaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaa-aaa
```

They are also telling you your Username:

```
User
aaaaaaaa-aaaaaaaaa-aaa
```

The Access Key and Secret Key can be used to identify yourself, as you have done with the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
Access key ID
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Secret access key
AAAAAAAAAAA/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

The next part is an IAM Policy:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect":"Allow",
            "Action": [ 
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::bbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbb/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy states that you can perform the listed actions against the specified Amazon S3 bucket.

It's not a great policy however, because the last 3 actions actually apply to a bucket (or no bucket), so should be not used with a `Resource` statement that specifies `bucket/*`.

If you are trying to access information in Amazon S3 but receive `Access Denied`, then contact your System Administrator to update the policy to grant you access.

Comment: Why didn't I use `User` anywhere? Why didn't I use bucket name anywhere? Where is bucket name to use?

Comment: You use Username/Password for the Console. You use Access/Secret Key for API calls or the CLI. They both identify the same User. If you want to use a bucket, you should specify it as part of the `aws s3 ls s3://bucket-name`.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have configured your credentials properly based on your update
   in the question.
2. But you haven't specified a default region in the configuration.
   Check with your admins what is the region for this S3 bucket. It
   could be something like `us-east-1` or `us-west-2`.
3. Once you have your bucket's region, you can issue a command as
   below: 
   `aws s3 ls <name of your bucket> --region us-east-1`

The reason you are receiving access denied is you do not have access to other buckets, but only one of the buckets on S3. This is suggested by this line:

```
"Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::bbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbb/*"
```

Where bbbbbbbb-bbbbbbbbb-bbbbbbb is name of you bucket.

Comment: Where is the name of bucket?

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to `IAM` to create a policy for your bucket. Than you need to add this policy to your users account and than you can access this bucket using your users AccessKey and SecretAccessKey

Comment: No, no, another use gave me this, and this is me who need to have access

Comment: yes if the policy is right you should be able to access the S3 bucket using the given AccessKey and SecretAccessKey

Comment: How to do this?

Comment: Depends on how you want to access the S3 bucket. There are several ways like AWS CLI e.g.

Comment: Can I access it from my S3 console?

Comment: No you can only access S3 buckets in your account from your console. If you want to access the S3 bucket via AWS console, you need a console user account for this S3 Bucket account

Comment: Okay, what is this file for then? What is it's purpose? What program is intended to read it?

Comment: That file is for your eyeballs.  They are giving you an access key id and secret and telling you about the policy they applied.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot did I use this information correctly?